# new to fragments - one class knows where to find method implementation which is in another class

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee

I was going through [vogella's fragment tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html) and I came across this method call in the MyListFragment class:

```
listener.onRssItemSelected(newTime);
```

However, this onRssItemSelected method is actually defined(implemented) in the RssfeedActivity class. SO my questions, how did MyListFragment class know to go to the RssfeedActivity class to find the onRssItemSelected method?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely he is implementing a callback to allow the fragments to communicate with each other.  The following link explains the process much better than I ever could:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html